# How do I select a popup window in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I don't need to create a window, I need to select one that the browser automatically opened.

How can I do this in cypress?

```
it.only('Login with Torus', () => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/auth');
        cy.get('button.button-torus span').click();
        // need to target new popup window here from 3rd party auth
        cy.get('input#passwordless-email').type('ettinger+test@gmail.com');
    });
```

This is a 3rd party auth service called Torus. https://app.tor.us/

Comment: can you show us the webpage link or sample page where the popup shows up

Comment: No it’s not on web anywhere. But it’s similar to oath for blockchain

Comment: Here is the login page that opens in a new window https://app.tor.us/

Answer (score 4):

From Cypress [Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#Permanent-trade-offs)

> Permanent trade-offs:
>
> - There will never be support for multiple browser tabs.
> - You cannot use Cypress to drive two browsers at the same time.

"Because Cypress runs in the browser, it will never have multi-tabs support. We do have access to the browser automation APIs to actually switch tabs, but there is no reason for us to ever expose them."

Same [doc](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#Permanent-trade-offs) also leads to few examples  on working this around:

- [Tab Handling and Links](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links)
- [Logging In](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes#Logging-In)